# How MAX of a concatenated column in oracle works?

Tags: oracle, max, concatenation

In Oracle, while trying to concatenate two columns of both Number type and then trying to take MAX of it, I am having a question.
i.e column A column B of Number data type,

```
Select MAX(A||B) from table
```

Table data

```
A           B
20150501    95906
20150501    161938
```

when I’m running the query `Select MAX(A||B)` from table

O/P - `2015050195906`

Ideally `20150501161938` should be the output????

I am trying to format column B like TO_CHAR(B,'FM000000') and execute i'm getting the expected output.

```
Select MAX(A || TO_CHAR(B,'FM000000')) FROM table
```

O/P - `2015011161938`

Why is `2015050195906` is considered as MAX in first case.

Comment: Because you are comparing strings, not numbers `A||B` results in an implicit data type conversion from a number to a character value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, column A is a date and column B is a time.

If that's true, treat them as such:

```
select max(to_date(to_char(a)||to_char(b,'FM000000'),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) from your_table;
```

That will add a leading space for the time component (if necessary) then concatenate the columns into a string, which is then passed to the to_date function, and then the max function will treat as a DATE datatype, which is presumably what you want.

PS: The real solution here, is to fix your data model.  Don't store dates and times as numbers.  In addition to sorting issues like this, the optimizer can get confused.  (If you store a date as a number, how can the optimizer know that '20141231' will immediately be followed by '20150101'?)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert to number;

```
select MAX(TO_NUMBER(A||B)) from table
```

Comment: Not really. If you do that, then `20150102 11111` will be considered smaller than `20150101 123456`

Comment: So? 2015010211111 < 20150101123456 it is true. what is the wrong?

Comment: In my book, January 2nd is after January 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation will result in a character/text output. As such, it sorts alphabetically, so `9` appears after `16`.

In the second case, you are specifiying a format to pad the number to six digits. That works well, because `095906` will now appear before `161938`.